# Cannot "proxy" replication on CouchDB to PouchDB sync

Tags: node.js, express, couchdb, pouchdb

In order to not expose my DB in an Node.JS application I tried to create a gateway between CouchDB and the Internet by simply relaying the requests and responses between the two server to keep an authentication layer controlled by me. At first I tried to write the proxy myself but after the difficulties I chose to you [node-http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) to do that, see the example:

```
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
    proxy.web(req, res, {'target': 'http://127.0.0.1:5984'});
});
```

On the other side side of the application I used the PouchDB "pouchdb-getting-started-todo".
Not much details needed here, suffice it to say that whenever I connect the "pouchdb-getting-started-todo" directly to the CouchDB the sync was completed with no errors, but every attempt with my proxy server appeared to start fine, logging the request objects, iterating eleven times and in the front end it eventually thrown ETIMEDOUT:

```
n {code: "ETIMEDOUT", status: 0, result: {…}}
code
:
"ETIMEDOUT"
result
:
{ok: false, start_time: Sat May 12 2018 02:45:52 GMT-0300 (-03), docs_read: 0, docs_written: 0, doc_write_failures: 0, …}
status
:
0
__proto__
:
Error
```

Since CouchDB is an REST API I would expect to be able to do that. Does anyone know, is this is expected behavior or an anomaly?

Comment: There's no reason you shouldn't be able to proxy requests to CouchDB. I do this regularly, and it's a common practice. I'm not a node programmer, so can't comment on your specific configuration, though.

Comment: What are the CORS accesses needed? Perhaps this my bring me some light.